# get previous td element to manipulate in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

How would I go about grabbing the previous `td` element in a table in order to change it's `text` value inside an Ajax call?

This is what i have so far. I think I am grabbing the `td` element properly and placing it into the variable, however I cannot get an alert to pop up with the text on the `td` element I'm trying to alter and I can't actually change the text like I'm trying to do.

```
    function ChangeStatus(id) {
        var td = $(this).parent('td').prev();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("changeStatus","AgentTransmission")',
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                td.empty();
                td.html("Hold");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Edit**

Here are the two `td` elements I'm working with. When the user clicks the `Hold` link w/the `ChangeStatus()` `onclick` event, I want to be able to change the text of the previous element from `Waiting` to `Hold`.

```
<td>
Waiting
</td>
<td>
<a href="/AgentTransmission/Details/17">Details</a>           
    <span> | </span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ChangeStatus(17)" >Hold</a> 
</td>
<td align=center id=17>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you post your rendered HTML table structure? As of right now, we have no way of telling you if you got the right `td`.

Comment: why use empty() if you are using html()? html() replace any content

Comment: Just posted the HTML, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, parent() only get the first parent, if the caller is deeper in the dom, you won't get it. You should use parents(), but i'd recommend using classes instead of tag names, something like this:

```
$(this).parents('td.myClass').prev();
```

You can also use:

```
console.log(myString);
```

instead of alerts, you can see the result in the console, using chrome or firebug in firefox

Hope it helps

Comment: How would i alter the value inside the `td` variable? Neither of these work: `td.empyt()` or `td.html('Hold')`

Comment: Since i wasn't using classes, removing the `td.myClass` worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `td` like this:

```
var td = $(this).closest('td');
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. does this work if the `td` element is not the last in the `tr`?

Comment: lol actually this works.. but it grabs the source `td` element. So basically this code: `var td = $(this).closest('td');` combined with this `td.html('Hold');` puts the text `Hold` in the `td` element that is calling the function, not the previous one.